# How can you select entries in a FTS SQL db that only matches part of the query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, match

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TEST USING FTS5(SomeText);

INSERT INTO TEST(SomeText) VALUES 
('Covid 19');

SELECT SomeText 
FROM TEST 
WHERE SomeText MATCH 'sars covid 19';
```

=> no results

How could I make sure this also returns the column with 'Covid 19'? Is there an extension or function that considers this to keep the sql command simple?

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=defbd331c8469e05ea6a107df10738a2

Comment: Perhaps I'm oversimplifying or misunderstanding the example, but wouldn't searching "covid 19" produce the desired results whether "sars" is included or not?

Comment: yeah I didn't explain very well, I edited the question to make it more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax to be used in such case is 'Covid 19 OR sars'.

For instance :

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TEST USING FTS5(SomeText);

INSERT INTO TEST(SomeText) VALUES 
('Sars'),
('Covid 19'),
('Covid 19 but also Sars'),
('Some other stuff');

SELECT SomeText 
FROM TEST 
WHERE SomeText MATCH 'Covid 19 OR sars';
```

Returns the following results :

```
Sars
Covid 19
Covid 19 but also Sars
```

You can check the following fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=27a80a1d85a9e314a145ffbe4c7f3edf)

See also : [https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/)

Comment: Hey, that's not what I meant, but I didn't explain it too well. I edited my question now to make it more clear

Comment: @SirNoob I edited my answer accordingly. Is it what you re looking for?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could use operators in the string with FTS5!